# List<List<Double>> to double[][] for JAMA or other libs

Tags: java, list, double, jama

i cannot get my List> to double[][] to work on linear algebra package like [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/).
Basically i have some sort of List with coordinates like this :

```
[[2.63, 11.087, -12.054], 
[2.357, 13.026, -15.29], 
[1.365, 16.691, -15.389], 
[0.262, 18.241, -18.694]]
```

And i am trying to put these coordinates to [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/) class which is double[][].
I tried to use method toArray, but i failed.

```
double[][] array = list.toArray(new double[list.size()][]);
```

How to do that? Or is there other packages to cope with SVD, which i need here, using List of Lists?

Comment: What are you using to convert the List to multi array?

Comment: "How to do that?" i suggest by trying to do that. When you have done this, show us what you have tried

Comment: I tried using something like `double[][] array = list.toArray(new double[list.size()][]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava has a [Doubles](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) class which has a `toArray` that takes a `Collection<? extends Number>` and will thereby take a `List<Double>` and convert to an array. So...

```
List<List<Double>> myList;
double[][] myArray = new double[myList.size()][];
for (int i=0, n<myList.size(); i<n; i++){
     myArray[i] = Doubles.toArray(myList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This is not working, `double[][] myArray = new double[myList.size()];` is missing a dimension, and after fixing that `myArray[i] = myList.get(i).toArray(new double[0]);` **toArray** method does not work here.

Comment: Sorry, updated above regarding array creation. What do you mean by "does not work here"? What is the error?

Comment: `The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (double[])`
This is the error i get.