# How can I transform a List of List (multidimensional List) to an Array of Array(multidimensional Array)?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have written this code, but at run time I have this error:

`[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.String;`
 please help me, thanks!!!

```
public  java.util.List<String>  concatAll(java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> mergedList) {



    java.lang.String [][] mergedArray = (String[][])mergedList.toArray();

    Iterator<java.util.List<String>> itr = mergedList.iterator();  
    java.util.List<String> list1 = itr.next();

          java.lang.String [] firstArray = (String[])list1.toArray();           

        int totalLength = firstArray.length;
          for (String[] array : mergedArray) {
            totalLength += array.length;
          }
          String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(firstArray, totalLength);
          int offset = firstArray.length;
          for (String[] array : mergedArray) {
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);
            offset += array.length;
          }
          java.util.List<String> finalList = Arrays.asList(result);
          for (String list : finalList)
              System.out.println(list);

    return finalList;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of mergedList?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689581/listlistdouble-to-double-for-jama-or-other-libs/16689909#16689909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box method, but it's fairly straightforward to do by hand:

```
// Create the outer dimension of the array, with the same size as the total list
String[][] mergedArray = new String[mergedList.size()][];

// Now iterate over each nested list and convert them into the String[]
// instances that form the inner dimension
for (int i = 0; i < mergedList.size(); i++) {
    mergedArray[i] = mergedList.get(i).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

---

A slightly more efficient version of the loop body would be

```
List<String> innerList = mergedList.get(i);
String[] innerAsArray = innerList.toArray(new String[innerList.size()]);
mergedArray[i] = innerAsArray;
```

as this avoids the array resizing that would be required in my initial example (the `new String[0]` isn't large enough to hold the list elements).  But quite frankly, unless this was a performance critical loop, I'd prefer the first version as I find it slightly clearer to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

`mergedList.toArray()` creates a singly indexed array typed as objects.

Each of the objects it contains is in fact a (singly-indexed) list of strings, though with this call syntax the type is not known at compile-time.  It is not an array of strings, as would be needed for your cast to work.

Since your `concatAll` is trying to convert a `List<List<String>>` into a `List<String>` by some sort of concatenation operation, it may be best to do this without ever converting to a `String[][]` at all, but if you do want that conversion, it can be done as follows:

```
private String[][] toDoubleIndexArray(List<List<String>> mergedList) {
    String[][] result = new String[mergedList.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i< mergedList.size(); i++) {
        List<String> currentList =  mergedList.get(i);
        result[i] = currentList.toArray(new String[currentList.size()]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Original answer, not quite correct as noted by Xavi Lopez in comments:**

Since `mergedList` has type `List<List<String>>`, 
`mergedList.toArray()` has type `List<String>[]`, i.e., it's an array of lists, and not a doubly indexed array.

Comment: Wouldn't `mergedList.toArray()` be of type `Object[]` instead? And wouldn't `mergedList.toArray(new List[0])` give a `List[]` ?

Comment: Actually, yes, you'd lose the type information.  I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you cannot convert the Multi dimentional String list to String array directly. Add the below code before trying to use the mergedArray:

```
/** Create Array **/     
String [][] mergedArray = new String[mergedList.size()][];

/** Initialize array from list **/  
for(int i=0; i< mergedList.size(); i++){
     mergedArray[i] = mergedList.get(i).toArray(new String[0]);
 }
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think your return type is wrong if your intention is to return an array of array.

Try this:

```
public String[][] concatAll(java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> mergedList) {

    //java.lang.String [][] mergedArray = (String[][])mergedList.toArray();
    java.lang.String[][] mergedArray = new String[mergedList.size()][];

    Iterator<java.util.List<String>> itr = mergedList.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        java.util.List<String> list1 = itr.next();
        String[] array1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
        mergedArray[count++] = array1;
    }


return mergedArray;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't convert a

```
List<List<String>>
```

to a String[][] by using the out of the box toArray functionality. This would only work if you had:

```
List<String[]>.
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert between a list of list string and a multi dimensional string array?  Yes, Of course you can as long as you write some custom logic. You can't do it via toArray as u were trying though unless its a list of string array instead